# How to load a UITable with custom cell inside a UICollectionViewCell that is already a NIB

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, nib

I have a UICollection view that has two custom cells.  The UICollectionViewCell  custom cells are built using NIB's.  Inside one of the UICollectionViewCell NIB's, I have a UITableView.  However, the UITableView itself has custom cells.  So my question is:

How do I load a custom cell for the UITableView instead a UICollectionViewCell  NIB?

```
import UIKit

class HeaderFooterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    //Tableview
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //Buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var periodButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var undoButton: UIButton!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        // Register cell classes
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ShotInformationTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

}

extension HeaderFooterCollectionViewCell: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ShotInformationTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cell =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("XIB_File_Name", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! XIB_Class_Name
```

In almost all cases , `XIB_File_Name == XIB_Class_Name`

Comment: Hey @PaulS. I am using my answer while returning `cellForItem` but unfortunately it crashed , even if use `let cell = UINib(nibName: "XIB_File_Name", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! XIB_Class_Name` the result is same , so how did my answer worked for you ?

Comment: This is my code `let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ShotInformationTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ShotInformationTableViewCell` works fine with no crashes.

Comment: Sorry , I'm asking in case of Collection View !